# "The maximum array length quota..." WCF solution

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Have a specific problem with my ASP.NET application using WCF.
I have a table in my database with binary field for image storing.
I can read and write binary array of the image using .net entity without any problem.
But when I use WCF, have some problems.

changing the web.config of my web application (increasing array quota) I solved the problem with reading binary array using WCF
but still have problems with writing this array using WCF.
I have such kind of message:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:question. The InnerException message was 'There
>   was an error deserializing the object of type SL.DTO.QuestionDTO. The
>   maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML
>   data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength
>   property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating
>   the XML reader. Line 1, position 55410.'.

this is my web.config of WEB application:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>        
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDAI_ExamenationService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>        
      </basicHttpBinding>      
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:22840/DAI_ExamenationService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDAI_ExamenationService"
        contract="DAI_ExamenationServiceReference.IDAI_ExamenationService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IDAI_ExamenationService" /> 
    </client>    
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and this is the web.config of service application:

```
<system.serviceModel>    
    <behaviors>      
      <serviceBehaviors>        
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

I think I should change permissions in web.config of service to solve this problem but don't know which are...true

Comment: You need to have the readerQuotas both on the client and server for the exception to get resolved. Add the same readerQuotas settings on your service as well